Is there a better way to initialize a dataframe from a list of rows, in C#/F#
I have an array of DataFrameRow objects and want to add them to one another to make a DataFrame object.
It looks like I have to initialize the DataFrame with a list of columns before I can use the append function, so I have to take the first row, parse the columns, add them and then add all the rows.
This gives the following code (F#):
        // extract the columns from the first row
        let columns =
            dfRows[0].GetValues()
|> Seq.map (fun x -> match x.Value with
| :? DateTime -> DateTimeDataFrameColumn(x.Key, [| x.Value :?> DateTime |]) :> DataFrameColumn
| :? int      -> Int32DataFrameColumn   (x.Key, [| x.Value :?> int |])      :> DataFrameColumn
| :? single   -> SingleDataFrameColumn  (x.Key, [| x.Value :?> single|])   :> DataFrameColumn
| :? double   -> DoubleDataFrameColumn  (x.Key, [| x.Value :?> double |])   :> DataFrameColumn
| :? bool     -> BooleanDataFrameColumn (x.Key, [| x.Value :?> bool |])     :> DataFrameColumn
| :? string   -> StringDataFrameColumn  (x.Key, [| x.Value :?> string |])   :> DataFrameColumn
| _           -> failwith $"unsupported value type for column \"{x.Key}\": {x.Value.GetType()}"
            )

        // initialize the dataframe with the extracted columns
        let df = DataFrame(columns)

        // append the rows to the dataframe
        let df = df.Append(dfRows[1..], inPlace = true)

Is there a better / shorter / more convenient way to do this?

What's the source? If it's CSV then in C# you would probably want to use CsvHelper Nuget. I am unfamiliar with F#, but I would guess, it would be compatible, too?

The data is built in the code, it’s a bunch of data frames with the same columns but a different number of rows and I need to append all the rows together into a single data frame. It’s not really a language issue, a solution in C# is the same, it’s more about not finding the right way with the DF api.

I've never used Microsoft.Data.Analysis, so I cannot comment on the general approach. From a purely F# perspective, you may at least eliminate the downcasts and shorten on the upcasts.

You can provide type parameters to Seq.map
You can use the as form of the dynamic type test

That results in something like:
let columns =
    dfRows[0].GetValues()
    |> Seq.map<_,DataFrameColumn> (fun x ->
        match x.Value with
        | :? DateTime as v -> DateTimeDataFrameColumn(x.Key, [| v |]) :> _
        | :? int      as v -> Int32DataFrameColumn   (x.Key, [| v |]) :> _
        | :? single   as v -> SingleDataFrameColumn  (x.Key, [| v |]) :> _
        | :? double   as v -> DoubleDataFrameColumn  (x.Key, [| v |]) :> _
        | :? bool     as v -> BooleanDataFrameColumn (x.Key, [| v |]) :> _
        | :? string   as v -> StringDataFrameColumn  (x.Key, [| v |]) :> _
        | _           as v -> failwith "!" )

